# Explain delimiter for java tokenizer

Tags: java, delimiter

Explain this:

```
"\t\n\r\">#"
```

it's used in Java tokenizer.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\">#");
```

Comment: why is this question getting all these downvotes?  The OP just didn't know what he was looking at...

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Comment: Actually, now that you have removed all reference to regular expressions, the question is a bit pointless. You know now what this thing is (we told you that already). You know it's a set of delimiters and not a regex. So are you still struggling with understanding, or is it all cleared up.

Comment: Thank you David Heffernan for your response. I've removed all reference to regular expression so people who think i've asked about regexp and actually i didn't (because i'm stupid obvioulsy) don't come here to help me.. quesion was misleading and that's why i've removed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a delimiter set for the tokenizer. It is not a regular expression as you originally suspected.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) of the `StringTokenizer` constructor:

> The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String%29) for the constructor overload that does not have the `delim` argument gives an idea of what type of string might be expected:

> Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. The tokenizer uses the default delimiter set, which is `" \t\n\r\f"`: the space character, the tab character, the newline character, the carriage-return character, and the form-feed character. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

The code you have is specifying a different set of delimiters from the default.

Answer (score 2):

- `\t` is a character meaning "[horizontal tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_Tab#Tab_characters)"
- `\n` is a character meaning "[line feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed)" (LF)
- `\r` is a character meaning "[carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)" (CR)

As for the question itself, it's not a regular expression but a set of delimiter characters.

---

**Resources :**

- [Wikipedia - new line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regexp,this means

\t is tab
\n is end of line
\r is carriage return
\" is " character
">" and "#" are the respective characters.

This string tokenizer will break the string "remaining" into tokens, separating the string in any of the previous characters.